# Saving properties of external platform in custom admin page in magento2

Tags: admin, magento2, phtml

I've added a tab to the admin menu with our company's page, which enables the user to insert and define his own properties of our widget (input fields of secret and key). Now I would like magento's server to save these values upon clicking the page's 'save' button, and show them next time the user loads the page.
previously we did that inside system.xml:

```
 field id="key" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1"  showInStore="1">
 field id="secret" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1"  showInStore="1">
```

I tried to translate this to .phtml (simple html input text) but not sure magento2 supports other formats except her attributes in xml files.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[image]In Magento 2, you can achieve this by using the same system.xml file placed under app/code/`Vendor`/`Package`/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom_module" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Progos</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom_module_section" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom Module</label>
            <tab>custom_module</tab>
            <resource>Progos_Custom::custom_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>API Settings</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="api" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>API</label>
                    <comment>This is comment for this field.</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="secret" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Secret Key</label>
                    <comment>This is comment for this field.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system> </config>
```

Please have a look at attached image too.

If you still have any confusion, let us know!
Good Luck!